# Getting exception while running cucumber with junit / Testng

Tags: java, selenium, junit, cucumber, testng

i'm not able to run the Cucumber TestRunner class with both testng/Junit. i want to have Testng and junit in my framework. i'm getting some abstarct class error. i have all the dependencies in my project. I have 2qns here.
1.can i use Testng annotations in my cucumber scripts as `RunWith` is importing from cucumber junit
2.how to solve the error execute my testRun.

#### TestRunner class

```
package testRun;


import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import io.cucumber.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features="/OpenCart/src/test/resources/testFeature",glue= {"stepDefinitions"},
plugin = { "pretty", "html:target/cucumber-reports" })

public class TestRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests{

}
```

#### Error log

```
java.lang.annotation.AnnotationFormatError: Invalid default: public abstract java.lang.Class io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions.objectFactory()
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.getDefaultValue(Method.java:612)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationType.<init>(AnnotationType.java:132)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationType.getInstance(AnnotationType.java:85)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(AnnotationParser.java:266)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:120)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:72)
    at java.lang.Class.createAnnotationData(Class.java:3521)
    at java.lang.Class.annotationData(Class.java:3510)
    at java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(Class.java:3415)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.IgnoredBuilder.runnerForClass(IgnoredBuilder.java:10)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:70)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:37)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:70)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.createRunner(ClassRequest.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.MemoizingRequest.getRunner(MemoizingRequest.java:19)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createUnfilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

#### Folder Structure

[image: Maven Dependency]

#### Dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.0</version>
</dependency>
  
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-junit -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
    <version>5.7.0</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.2</version>
</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.0</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/gherkin -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
    <version>13.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-testng -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.0</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.0</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-jvm-deps -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.6</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.2</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.aventstack/extentreports -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.5</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.2</version>
</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.141.59</version>
</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
    <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.1</version>
</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-all -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.19</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

is i'm missing anything... if i'm missing anything please help me  to fix this.

Comment: why do you need both junit and testng in your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Errors about missing methods, or methods not being allowed where they are are typically caused by a mismatch of dependencies. So if you look at your pom you'll see that you are using different versions of Cucumber. Additionally you are including transitive dependencies that you do not strictly need.

From `io.cucumber` you should only need `cucumber-java` and `cucumber-junit` or `cucumber-testng`. All other dependencies are transitive and will be included with the right version automatically by maven.

I would also suggest trying to get either junit or testng to work. Trying to make both work at the same time just makes it more complicated for you.

Comment: Look like your point is a valid one. I will try this one and will update you..

Comment: i tried to run by commenting the cucumber-testng but still i am getting the same error.

Comment: I suggested that you try multiple things. By removing `cucumber-testng` you've only done one. And since you are using Eclipse don't forget to reimport/refresh your project after making changes to the pom.

Comment: That issue is resolved and yes your suggestions worked for me.. Can you please look in this issue.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62189075/getting-no-backend-were-found-in-cucumber-junit

Answer (score 1):

If you want Junit and Testng in the same project then it is better to create two different runners because running the runner file extending AbstractTestNGCucumberTests with junit leads to that issue. From my perspective, you can create two different runner files and then in the maven pom.xml you can create different profiles for both Junit and Testng

Comment: I got your point but i am not even able to run with junit..irrespective of Testng.. I'm getting the above mentioned exception