# Getting No Backend were found in cucumber junit

Tags: java, selenium, maven, junit, cucumber

I'm trying to run the cucumber testRunner with junit but i'm getting the No backends were found exception. i found similiar exeception solutions but they are getting runtime exceptions and mine is different to that exception. can some one look into it.

#### testRunner

```
package testRun;


import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import io.cucumber.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features="/OpenCart/src/test/resources/testFeature",glue= {"stepDefinitions"},
plugin = { "pretty", "html:target/cucumber-reports" })

public class TestRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests{

}
```

#### Exception

```
io.cucumber.core.exception.CucumberException: No backends were found. Please make sure you have a backend module on your CLASSPATH.
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.BackendServiceLoader.get(BackendServiceLoader.java:36)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.BackendServiceLoader.get(BackendServiceLoader.java:30)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.ThreadLocalRunnerSupplier.createRunner(ThreadLocalRunnerSupplier.java:50)
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal$SuppliedThreadLocal.initialValue(ThreadLocal.java:284)
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal.setInitialValue(ThreadLocal.java:180)
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:170)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.ThreadLocalRunnerSupplier.get(ThreadLocalRunnerSupplier.java:44)
    at io.cucumber.junit.PickleRunners$NoStepDescriptions.run(PickleRunners.java:146)
    at io.cucumber.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:83)
    at io.cucumber.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:185)
    at io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:83)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber$RunCucumber.evaluate(Cucumber.java:219)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

i have all the dependencies in my pom file and please find the below dependency details

#### dependency details

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.7.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
  
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-junit -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
    <version>5.7.0</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.2</version>
</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.7.0</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/gherkin -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
    <version>13.0.0</version>
</dependency>

 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-testng -->
<!--<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.0-RC2</version>
</dependency> -->

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-gherkin -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-gherkin</artifactId>
    <version>5.7.0</version>
</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-jvm-deps -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.6</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.2</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.aventstack/extentreports -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.5</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.2</version>
</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.141.59</version>
</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
    <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.1</version>
</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-all -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.19</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

#### FileStrcture

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating the cucumber jars to latest solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

use cucumber-Java dependency version 5.7.0